# SOR method for antisymmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I need some help with this problem:

> Let
>
> $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
>     1 & p \\
>     -p & 1 \\
> \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> Using SOR method, for which values of $\omega$ does the system converge?

I know, there is a theorem for symmetric matrices ($0<\omega<2$), but in this case tha matrix is antisymmetric.

I guess, I need to see the expression $H_\omega = (D-\omega L)^{-1}((1-\omega)D + \omega U)$ and the fact tha $H_\omega$ should has $\lambda<1$ but when I developed the characteristic polynomial, I get lost with very great results and that make no sense

Comment: Are you given any restrictions on the values of p?

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic polynomial of $H_\omega$ is

$$
r(x) = x^2 - (\omega^2p^2 + 2(1-\omega))x + (1-\omega)^2
$$

and the eigenvalues of $H_\omega$ are given by

$$
\frac{\omega^2p^2 + 2(1-\omega) \pm \omega|p|\sqrt{\omega^2p^2 + 4(1-\omega)}}{2}
$$

We may assume that $\omega\in (0,2)$, otherwise the SOR method does not converge. I further assume that $p$ is real. Now suppose that $|p| \geq 1$. Then it follows that both eigenvalues are real. Moreover

$$
\left(\omega|p|\sqrt{\omega^2p^2 + 4(1-\omega)}\,\right)^2 - (w^2p^2 - 2\omega)^2 = 4\omega^2(p^2-1) \geq 0,
$$

which implies that

$$
|w^2p^2 - 2\omega| \leq \omega|p|\sqrt{\omega^2p^2 + 4(1-\omega)}
$$

From this result we observe that

$$
2 \leq w^2p^2 + 2(1-\omega) + \omega|p|\sqrt{\omega^2p^2 + 4(1-\omega)} \implies \rho(H_\omega) \geq 1
$$

Thus, the SOR method does not converge for all $\omega\in (0,2)$ if $|p| \geq 1$.

Now suppose that $|p| < 1$. Then the eigenvalues are real if $0 < \omega \leq (2/p^2)(1-\sqrt{1-p^2})$ and are imaginary otherwise. In the case of imaginary eigenvalues you can show that $\rho(H_\omega) = |1-\omega| < 1$ by arguments similar to those above. In the case of real eigenvalues I will leave it up to you to show that

$$
\left|\omega^2p^2 + 2(1-\omega) \pm \omega|p|\sqrt{\omega^2p^2 + 4(1-\omega)}\,\right|  < 2
$$

and hence that $\rho(H_\omega) < 1$ for all $\omega\in(0,2)$ and all $|p| < 1$.